# Rundeck job, ping dns: might be active or inactive

Tags: workflow, rundeck

I'm trying to make a simple Rundeck job.

Step 1 ask you for a DNS and pings it.

If active, then run step 2 with a simple echo "step 2 ok"

But if ping fails, should skip step 2 and run only step 3.

There must be 3 steps, but only 2 runs.

Anyway some can help me with this?

I tried to use ruleset workflow, but can't figure out how to tell step 2 to run or skip it

Answer (score 0):

The Ruleset strategy approach is exclusively for Process Automation product.

On Rundeck Open Source, you can create a [data passing](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/passing-variables.html#passing-data-between-steps) based workflow in the following way:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 9098cc06-84bd-4d5c-bd14-c792b0bd2fa7
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ExampleJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: dns_name
    value: google.com
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            regex: ^(result)\s*=\s*(.+)$
            replaceFilteredResult: 'false'
          type: key-value-data
      script: ping -c 1 @option.dns_name@ ; echo result=$?
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        if [ @data.result@ -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "all ok! ping!"
        else
            echo "host unreachable."
        fi
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 9098cc06-84bd-4d5c-bd14-c792b0bd2fa7
```

Basically, this approach "merges" the steps 2 and 3 in a single script which decides depending on the step 1 ping result.

You can [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) this YAML [job definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/terminology.html#job-definition) on your instance to test it.